# Get element position by class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, position

Below is what my code looks like, basically, I want to get the positon of li with a class name of "default".

```
<ul id="parent_wrap">
  <li class="normal"></li>
  <li class="normal"></li>
  <li class="default"></li>
  <li class="normal"></li>
  <li class="normal"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You should use ids. Classes are for collections as demonstrated in your example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **[index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/)** as shown :-

```js
alert(  $(".default").index() );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="parent_wrap">
  <li class="normal"></li>
  <li class="normal"></li>
  <li class="default"></li>
  <li class="normal"></li>
  <li class="normal"></li>
</ul>
```

Or give a unique **id** to `li` say `'myli'` and try this :-

```
alert(  $("#myli").index() );
```

Comment: @user3788364..Great..!!!...but as mentioned by Ed Heal try using id's instead of class...happy to help you :)

Comment: @Kartikeya - Ids should be used - not classes